# create xml with attributes programmatically

Tags: c#, xml

I've read around and I couldn't find any good example of how to do this. The file I'm trying to create programmatically looks like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
  <head>
    <title> title here </title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <xsl:apply-templates />
  </body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="data">
<table width="400" border="1">
  <tr bgcolor="#a0acbc">
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <xsl:for-each select="row">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </xsl:for-each>
</table>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I've seen some examples but I don't know how to make it look exactly like this, with the "stylesheet xmlns:xls=...." and with the attributes on the table and tr.

Could someone help me with this or post me some good example of this?

Comment: Have you looked at any of `XDocument`, `XmlDocument` or `XmlWriter` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use namespaces (that is the "xsl:" in the names of the elements.)

I'm not going to do the whole thing for you, but this should help point you in the right direction:
You'll need to prefix the element names and attributes with namespaces like so:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace XSLCreator
{
   class Program
   {
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
         XNamespace xsl = XNamespace.Get("http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform");

         var doc = new XDocument(
             new XElement(xsl + "stylesheet",
                 new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsl", xsl),
                 new XAttribute("version", "1.0")
             )
         );

         var sw = new StreamWriter("test.xml");
         XmlWriter xw = new  XmlTextWriter(sw);
         doc.WriteTo(xw);
         xw.Close();
         sw.Close();
      }
   }
}
```

You'll get an xml doc that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" />
```

Comment: Personally I would use XmlWriter.WriteStartElement, XmlWriter.WriteAttribute, XmlWriter.WriteEndElement etc rather than creating a document in memory and then serializing it.